# Update border title when JmenuItem is clicked

Tags: java, swing

My question is a little complicated please,Am trying to update the borderTitle of a Jpanel when a JMenuItem is clicked,i have 3 classes,A implements ActionListener, B is the JPanel class and C is the JFrame class,here is what i have tried already

```
public class PanelTitle implements ActionListener{
     String title;
    public PanelTitle(){
    }                     
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         SedimentPanel sp = new SedimentPanel();
         sp.titledBorder.setTitle("SEDIMENT");

         sp.repaint();
         sp.revalidate();


    }
}
```

i have this in my JFrame class

```
 velocityMenuItem.addActionListener(new PanelTitle());
```

here is my JPanel class

```
public class SedimentPanel extends JPanel{
    public SedimentPanel(){
        super();
        initComponents();
        initPlaceHolders();
        setBorder(titledBorder); 

    }

    TitledBorder titledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "border title",TitledBorder.CENTER,TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION);

}
```

please how do i really get the borderTitle to change when i click a JMenuItem?
Here is how i referenced it in the frame class,now i get a Nullpointer Exception

```
public class FrameClass extends JFrame{
private static SedimentPanel sp;
    public FrameClass(SedimentPanel sp){
        this.sp = sp;}
}
public static void main(String args[]){
 FrameClass fc = new FrameClass(sp);
}
```

Comment: Per the [TitledBorder API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html) the class has a method, `public void setTitle(String)` -- why not simply call this method on the border, changing its text?

Comment: Ah, you're making a newbie mistake of creating a new SedimentPanel instance: `SedimentPanel sp = new SedimentPanel();`. This is not the same as the one displayed. This suggests that you need to better understand the concept of what an object is and what it represents. A new SediementPanel is just that a ***NEW*** object. Calling a method on this **new** reference won't have any effect on the existing instance. Get the appropriate reference and call the method on that. Pass the reference in via setter method or constructor to set a field.

Comment: How do i reference it properly bro? @Hovercraft

Comment: How do you reference **any** object? The same way

Comment: Never edit someone's answer to your own question as that is considered vandalism of the answer. Instead update your original question via [edit].

Comment: Alright bro,i just want to get this sorted out,it's taken me all day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making a basic mistake here:

```
public class PanelTitle implements ActionListener{
     String title;
    public PanelTitle(){
    }                     
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         SedimentPanel sp = new SedimentPanel(); // ********
         sp.titledBorder.setTitle("SEDIMENT");

         sp.repaint();
         sp.revalidate();
    }
}
```

That new SedimentPanel is a completely new reference and calling a method on it will have no effect on the original displayed object. Don't do this, get the appropriate reference and call the method on it.

```
public class PanelTitle implements ActionListener{
    String title;
    private SedimentPanel sp;

    public PanelTitle(SedimentPanel sp){  // pass in reference
        this.sp = sp;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         // SedimentPanel sp = new SedimentPanel(); // ******** NO
         // sp.titledBorder.setTitle("SEDIMENT");
         sp.setTitle("SEDIMENT"); // better to give the class this method
         sp.repaint();
         sp.revalidate();
    }
}
```

```
public class SedimentPanel {
    private TitledBorder titledBorder = ....;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        titledBorder.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then when you create this listener, pass in the appropriate reference to the actual *visualized* JPanel.

That you're making this mistake suggests that it wouldn't harm you to read or re-read a decent chapter in your text on what an object/reference is and what it represents because this is a foundational mistake that you're making.

A working example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TitleExample {

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SedimentPanel sedimentPanel = new SedimentPanel();
        PanelTitle panelTitle = new PanelTitle(sedimentPanel); // pass in the reference
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("SEDIMENT");
        menuItem.addActionListener(panelTitle);
        JMenu jMenu = new JMenu("Menu");
        jMenu.add(menuItem);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(jMenu);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TitleExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sedimentPanel);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class SedimentPanel extends JPanel {
    private TitledBorder titledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "border title", TitledBorder.CENTER,
            TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION);

    public SedimentPanel() {
        super();
        setBorder(titledBorder);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        titledBorder.setTitle(title);
        repaint();
    }

}
```

```
class PanelTitle implements ActionListener{
    String title;
    private SedimentPanel sp;

    public PanelTitle(SedimentPanel sp){  // pass in reference
        this.sp = sp;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         sp.setTitle("SEDIMENT"); // better to give the class this method
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this to my JFrame class,but it didn't work   velocityMenuItem.addActionListener(new PanelTitle(new SedimentPanel()));

Comment: @chrisgeeq: for the love of god, don't you see that every time you create a new instance it's a completely new and unique instance?? Again, don't do that! Pass in the ***visualized*** SedimentPanel. Please read on OOPs without delay.

Comment: @chrisgeeq: only **you** have the original code and know where the reference to the original object exists. Get it. Pass it in. But don't create *new* anything here.

Comment: i will do that,but right now i have to get this sorted,help a brother pls

Comment: @chrisgeeq: I'm trying, but that's all I can do. You have the source code. If you're creating your ActionListener **within** the SedimentPanel class, then you would pass `this` into the listener's constructor. But again *we have no way of knowing how your code is wired*.

Comment: @chrisgeeq what Hovercraft is trying to say is: Imagine you have a piece of paper, you draw on it and want it to display on your book, but instead of grabbing this drawn paper, you're grabbing a new blank paper and placing it in your book, it's the same. Follow the above tips as your problem lies on it

Comment: @chrisgeeq: see edit with a working example. Note how references are created and passed. Note that `new SedimentPanel()` is called only once in my working example -- only one instance of this should be created.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro,your example is expected to work,but it still does not change the border-title,i don't know what is wrong anymore,i will upvote your answer once i get it working,thanks again.@Hovercraft

Comment: I followed your example to the letter,it still doesn't work @Hovercraft Full of Eels

Comment: It works really fine after i added a repaint() method at the end,thanks bro @Ho